# Dhall Repl: How to get the type of field of record type

Tags: dhall

I'm looking for a way to see the type of field of a record type, basically a type-level equivalent of `.` in the Dhall REPL

Suppose I've done:

```
:let Person = { name : Text, age : Natural }
```

How would I  find the type of Person.name (i.e. `Text`) *without* having to instantiate a Person?

If I create term of type Person, e.g. `:let betty : Person = { age = 34, name = "Betty" }`, I can do `:type betty.name`, but I'm looking for a type-level equivalent to that.

The practical use-case is for finding types of fields in `dhall-kubernetes` where there are deeply nested records with many fields.

Thanks, and apologies if my Google-fu failed and this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language does not support this yet, but I just opened an issue to track this idea:

https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/1079